# How to check arrays with numpy python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays and i want to check how many integers are the same in the different arrays. The problem i'm having is that it only shows me how many are the same when they are in the same position. Both arrays have 15 numbers in them. 
**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26])
b = np.array([8, 28, 12, 3, 24, 16, 23, 19, 14, 2, 11, 29, 27, 6, 13])
print(np.count_nonzero(a==b))
```

This prints **0** even though there's clearly integers that are the same. How can i make this print how many integers have the same value?

Comment: `(b == a[:, None]).sum()` might be what you're looking for?

Comment: What should the output be for the function you're looking for?

My guess is that you just shouldn't be using numpy, something like `len(set(a) & set(b))` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: `a == b` checks for "corresponding elements equality" `a[0] == b[0] and a[1] == b[1] and ...` see @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's comment for how to test one element against all aothers

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Is this the easiest way to do this or are there better ways?

Comment: @Linus Broadcasting really is the fastest way to do it.

Comment: Okey, thanks it worked.

Comment: import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26])
b = np.array([8, 28, 12, 3, 24, 16, 23, 19, 14, 2, 11, 29, 27, 6, 13])
total = np.intersect1d(a, b)
When i print 'total' I get: [14 19 23] How can i get the length of total instead? so in this case i want it to print 3

Comment: @Linus did you try using `len`???

Comment: @Linus Keep in mind that broadcasting is 3X faster than intersect1d on larger data, but consumes more memory.

Comment: should I do print(total.len)?

Comment: No, `len(total)`.

Comment: @Linus I'll bug you one more time to look at my post for a timing comparison, and then choose the method you prefer based on your data. Oh, and accept the answer you decide to use. Helps us all out. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah ofcourse! Thanks for explaining and showing a better and faster way to do it.

Comment: @Linus It turns out I had accidentally mistimed the results, and juan's answer is actually faster for larger data. I think you should accept his answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform broadcasted comparison between `b` and `a`, and then just tally up the matches:

```
(b == a[:, None]).sum()
3
```

This checks out since you have `[14, 19, 23]` as the common elements.

Comment: The variables bro!! It should be A and B na for timing?

Comment: @Bharath Oh ***, they should. I completely fricked that up, and the actual timings are vastly different.

Comment: Yeap. My kernel died to be honest :)

Comment: @Bharath Mine too, I am honestly a complete moron

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `np.intersect1d`, if I am understanding you correctly:

```
In [12]: import numpy as np

In [13]: a = np.array([1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26])
    ...: b = np.array([8, 28, 12, 3, 24, 16, 23, 19, 14, 2, 11, 29, 27, 6, 13])
    ...:

In [14]: np.intersect1d(a, b)
Out[14]: array([14, 19, 23])
```

Comment: juan, I'm so sorry. I accidentally messed up the timings in my post, and ended up misguiding OP against your answer. I'll let them know, hopefully they accept your answer instead. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks.